# C++: array of pointers to functions

Tags: c++, pointers

Say we have 2 functions

```
foo() { cout << "Hello"; }
foo2() { cout << " wolrd!"; }
```

how can i create an array of pointers (say `a`, `b`), with `a` pointing to `foo()` and `b` to `foo2()` ?
my goal is to store these pointers in an array A, then loop over A to execute these functions.

Comment: Since you're using C++ and not C use `std::function`, not raw pointers.

Comment: @Jepessen You don't need `std::function` as long as required. Normal function pointer type will also work for the given case.

Comment: @Jepessen: it is raw OWNING pointer we should avoid. regular pointer might be fine.

Comment: You forgot return type of function, whatever problems you have it's probably because compiler is in GNU (or other non-compliant) mode and default type is `int`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `my goal is to store these pointers in an array A, then loop over A to execute these functions.` In my opinion `std::function` is a better, cleaner and safer solution for achieving his goal. Then it's obviously possible to use raw pointers.

Comment: @Jepessen: Without additional `typedef`, C-array of `std::function` has better syntax than C-array of function pointer, indeed (but using `std::array` or `typedef` for the function pointer type would solve that). It is indeed safer, as it throw exception instead of UB for `nullptr`. Moreover `std::function` is more generic (as it accept also functors, as lambdas). But, genericity is not always wanted. On the other part, `std::function` has also overhead as type-erasure type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use typed function pointers as follows:

```
using FunPtrType = void(*)();

FunPtrType arr[]{&foo,  &foo2};
// or
std::array<FunPtrType, 2> arr2{&foo,  &foo2};

// ... do something with the array of free function pointers
// example
for(auto fun: arr2)
    fun();
```

Comment: I would recommend against type aliases for pointers. They make the program less obvious since they hide the asterisk.

Comment: im getting a "incomplete type is not allowed" on line std::array<FunPtrType, 2> arr2{&foo,  &foo2}; any ideas?

Comment: did you `#include <array>`? You do not need to specify the template parameters since C++17: https://godbolt.org/z/jMME54r75 Ah, and you forgot to specify the return type of your functions `foo()` ==> `void foo()`

Comment: @eerorika (IMO) the using makes the function pointer types better readable than `some retunr type(*)( a lot of arguments)` + easily editable throughout the code-base.

Comment: @eerorika matter of style. Some may argue that  `void (*arr[])() {&foo,  &foo2};` is less readable. It looks more like some lambda suffering a transport incident

Comment: @Const I didn't suggest to not use type aliases at all. Alias the function type instead. That way you don't need the galore of parentheses. It's the most readable approach in my opinion: `using Fun = void(); Fun* arr[] {foo, foo2};`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie See previous comment.

Comment: or `std::add_pointer_t<void()> arr[2];` :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// Defining test functions
void a(){cout<<"Function A"<<endl;}
void b(){cout<<"Function B"<<endl;}

int main()
{
    /*Declaring a vector of functions 
      Which return void and takes no arguments.
    */
    vector<void(*)()> fonc;
    //Adding my functions in my vector
    fonc.push_back(a);
    fonc.push_back(b);
    //Calling with a loop.
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        fonc[i]();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for typedefs these days, just use `auto`.

```
#include <iostream>
void foo1() { std::cout << "Hello"; }
void foo2() { std::cout << " world!"; }
auto foos = { &foo1, &foo2 };
int main() { for (auto foo : foos) foo(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are *two equivalent ways* to do what you want:

**Method 1**

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
void foo2() 
{ 
    std::cout << " wolrd!"; 
    
}


int main()
{
   
    void (*a)() = foo;// a is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything
    
    void (*b)() = foo2;// b is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything
    
    
    //create array(of size 2) that can hold pointers to functions that does not return anything and also does not take any parameter
    void (*arr[2])() = { a, b};
    
    arr[0](); // calls foo 
    
    arr[1](); //calls foo1
    
    return 0;
}
```

Method 1 can be executed [here](https://onlinegdb.com/phDfV2fQA).

**Method 2**

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
void foo2() 
{ 
    std::cout << " wolrd!"; 
    
}


int main()
{
   
    //create array(of size 2) that can hold pointers to functions that does not return anything
    void (*arr[2])() = { foo, foo2};
    
    arr[0](); // calls foo 
    
    arr[1](); //calls foo1
    
    return 0;
}
```

Method 2 can be executed [here](https://onlinegdb.com/P91pAX1hj).